# How to save data into android app before it being released?

Tags: android, assets

I am developing a app,there is a demand of serealizing some data into app ,when when it was  first actived,it can load data and display for customer from android app itself although there is no WIFI or any Net . I did some try, to save object into a file in src folder:/src/obj.txt ,but exception occurs when it started,can't find the definite file,another try was to save data into assets folder,but later I find out it is not writeable,so is there has some other method can resolve this,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the resources in your app aren't overwritable once installed.  Put them in the assets, and then store them on the SDCard, DB, or wherever after it is run so that you can access and update them later.

Comment: I got a solution ,I store it by json string in assets,when the app start first time, It will parser the json string to object firstly ,then store it into  my preference.Thanks!